# Updating a saved csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to save some data into a dict which i save into a csv file. The only problem is that i want to permanently save the csv file so i can re-use it later on when i restart the program. For instance, if i input some data it will show that the dict is updated and the csv file as well (if i open the csv file with excel it will show the input). But when i close the program and restart it again and give some new input, it will reset the dict and csv data. How can I keep the data and just update the file?
Here is my code, the comments are not important here.

```
# Writing
import csv

with open("inkomsten.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=":")

# Dicts van de data
inkomsten = {}
uitgaven = {}

##############################
```

It is only focused on "Inkomsten" at the moment.

```
# Inkomsten updaten
def toevoegenIn():
    bron = str(raw_input("Welke bron wilt U toevoegen? "))
    bedrag = int(input("Welk bedrag hoort daarbij? "))
    inkomsten[bron] = bedrag

# Uitgaven updaten
def toevoegenUit(bron, bedrag):
    uitgaven[bron] = bedrag

##############################

# Totaal bedragen updaten
def totaalIn():
    waarde = inkomsten.values()
    totaal = 0
    for i in waarde:
        totaal += i
    print totaal

def totaalUit():
    waarde = uitgaven.values()
    totaal= 0
    for i in waarde:
        totaal += i
    print totaal

##############################

toevoegenIn()
print inkomsten
totaalIn()

with open("inkomsten.csv", "wb") as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter=":")
    writer.writerows(inkomsten.items())
```

Comment: hog big are those files? Do they fit in memory? Also, could you post an example of 2-3 rows of the `.csv`?

Comment: Now, they are no more than around 20bytes because i tested it with only 1 input. An example is -> AH : 250 in one row. It will print every new input on a new row

Comment: I am also trying to separate the first and second input into two different columns, but that's for another time ;)

Comment: those .csv... are they ALWAYS gonna have only two columns? Like AH:250? (if that's the case, this could be done easily with a `dict`) otherwise, it's gonna be a bit more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make a couple of big assumptions here... If they're wrong, leave me a comment, and I'll try to edit my answer to make it more suitable to your question.

Let's assume the following:

- The data in your file will look like a `<key: value>` structure. That kind of structure fits very well in a python [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

  - This implicitly means that the `key`s (items on the left column) can't appear more than once in the file
- Your files are going to be small enough to be fully loaded in memory.

Considering those constraints, you can do something like this (comments in the code and some extra `print` statements for *debugging* purposes)

```
import csv


def toevoegenIn():
    bron = str(raw_input("Welke bron wilt U toevoegen? "))
    bedrag = int(input("Welk bedrag hoort daarbij? "))
    return {bron: bedrag}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Step 1: Load all the data in a dictionary. The cells might come with
    #         undesired extra spaces in them. Use strip to remove those.
    loaded_data = {}
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file_r:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file_r, delimiter=':')
        loaded_data = {}
        for row in reader:
            loaded_data[row[0].strip()] = int(row[1].strip())

    print "Initial data: %s" % loaded_data
    # Step 2: Ask the user what data to change.
    #         The toevoegenIn function will return a 
    #         one-key dictionary.
    change_data = toevoegenIn()
    # Step 3: Use dict.update to update your initial data with the
    #         dict retrieved above.
    #         If the modified key already existed in the original dict,
    #         it will be modified to the value entered by the user.
    #         If the key wasn't in the original dict, it'll be added.
    loaded_data.update(change_data)
    print "Updated data: %s" % loaded_data

    # Step 4: Write the new data. I put it into a new file, just 
    #         in case you don't wanna overwrite the original one. If
    #         you do want to overwrite, just change the file's name to
    #         the original file.
    with open('test.csv.new', 'w') as csv_file_w:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file_w, delimiter=':')
        for key, val in loaded_data.items():
            writer.writerow([key, val])

    # Make a quick confirmation read:
    with open('test.csv.new', 'r') as f:
        print "new_contents:\n%s" % f.read()
```

Which outputs:

```
Initial data: {'BD': 69, 'AH': 250, 'BC': 100}
Welke bron wilt U toevoegen? BC
Welk bedrag hoort daarbij? 150
Updated data: {'BD': 69, 'AH': 250, 'BC': 150}
new_contents:
BD:69
AH:250
BC:150
```

Comment: Oh I didn't even knew you could do this, but this will really help. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer solved your question, you should consider selecting it as the "selected answer" (the green tick to the left of the answer). It'll help people who find this question in the future, it'll give you rep., it'll give me rep., it'll encourage other people answer your questions in the future (OPs who systematically don't choose answers are not very well... perceived ) Win Win!! (for further reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 )

Answer (score 1):

To append new data to an existing file you will need to change the access mode when you opening the file from 'wb' to something like 'ab'.

Have a look at tutorial points page on reading files [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm), under the *The open Function* section there is a table which has the different options available. I know the example is not using the csv module but they seem to work and I have used some of them like 'ab' in the past.